# Can I capture video from an IP camera using OpenIMAJ?

Tags: java, web-applications, camera, ip-camera, openimaj

Using the `OpenIMAJ` library can I capture and record video from an IP camera and also show **live video** in a web application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not got an IP camera to test with, but in theory you can use the `XuggleVideo` class to do it - you basically just need to provide the URL of the stream provided by the camera:

```
Video<MBFImage> video = new XuggleVideo("rtsp://10.10.10.121/cam0_0");
```

Any type of stream/url that [FFmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org) supports should work.

Comment: I am getting an error "java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: rtsp".   video=new XuggleVideo("rtsp://192.168.1.109");